# Iterating Through Json file with Gson

Tags: java, json, gson

I'm new to json and I am trying to iterate through everything in this json file and trying to make a leaderboard for the top 5 people.

I don't know where to start, can someone point me in the right direction or give me an example?

Anything will help, thanks. Also, sorry for sounding so desperate it's for a school project haha.

Anyway, here's the json file. (It's in a kind of weird format, sorry for that)

I want to parse just the Elo from the top 5 and order them from highest Elo to the lowest.

```
{
   "347949075250806785": {
      "Elo": 1000,
      "Name": "deagan#0313"
   },
   "699447470144356434": {
      "Elo": 1001,
      "Name": "trendy#0001"
   },
   "294651035300003842": {
      "Elo": 1002,
      "Name": "SKRRRTT#0001"
   },
   "294651035300003843": {
      "Elo": 1003,
      "Name": "SKRRRTT#0002"
   },
   "294651035300003844": {
      "Elo": 1004,
      "Name": "SKRRRTT#0003"
   }
}
```

Like i said, anything helps. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Look up a tutorial for Gson - it should help you get started.

Basically you need to create a People object containing an inner Person class which contains `id`, `elo` & `name`, and then you do `Gson.fromJson(jsonString, People.class)` and it will convert the json string into objects which you can then sort through

https://howtodoinjava.com/gson/google-gson-tutorial/